# Is it a good practice to mix EJB business logic with non-EJB?

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb

I'm building a Java EE application from scratch, and most of it's parts are clear to me. Application server is Wildfly 9. The application uses maven as build tool. It builds application into ear archive and then deploys to server. Using EAR helped me a lot in understanding how Java EE layers depend on each other, but what bothers me now is whether I allowed to use non-ejb modules to contain business logic in it?

I'll try to explain.
My application modules are aligned in following hierarchy:

```
 ┌─────────────────────┐
 │ war (rest services) │
 └──────────┬──────────┘
 ┌──────────┴──────────────────┐
 │ ejb (em.persist, em.getAll) │ 
 └──────────┬──────────────────┘
 ┌──────────┴───────┐
 │ annotated models │
 └──────────────────┘
```

What I'm going to do is add a few modules that collect data asynchronously and store it in database. That modules are intended to collect data using different sources, analyze it and then place into database. Furthermore, one module should be able to run in few instances with different initial parameters. And lastly, these modules must be treated as plugins. If I exclude plugin from EAR, application should be able to start normally  and vice versa if I add a new module, application sees it and I can configure it's parameters by using my frontend.

How to do it correctly, allowing application to grow farther and using most-java-ee-way?
First thing coming to mind is to place plugins between ejb and model, add another module for persistence operations, and instantiate plugins with an object that can store data into database.

```
 ┌─────┐
 │ war │
 └──┬──┘
 ┌──┴──┬──────────┬─────────────┐
 │ ejb │ p.getAll │ initPlugins ├─────┐
 └─────┴────┬─────┴───┬─────────┘     │
            │    ┌────┴────┐     ┌────┴────┐
            │    │ plugin1 │ ... │ pluginN │
            │    └────┬────┘     └────┬────┘
┌───────────┴─────────┴───────────────┴───┐
│ ejb persistence (em.persist, em.getAll) │
└───────────┬─────────────────────────────┘
        ┌───┴───┐
        │ model │
        └───────┘
```

EJB layer can read settings from database, obtain plugins using Class.forName(plugin) method, supply plugins with persistence implementation and start them asynchronously. It is working, I know it because I did it just now. But one question bothers me: Am I doing it right?

Can plugins be managed by application server? Can wildfly create several EJBs from one class with different initial parameters? As far as I know, CDI allows me to inject several implementations of an interface to collection, but can I use it to insert second, third instance of the same class into that collection? It would be nice if someone make it clear to me. What I'm imagining now is depicted below:

```
 ┌─────┐
 │ war │
 └──┬──┘
 ┌──┴──┬───────────┬─────────────┐
 │ ejb │ em.getAll │ initPlugins ├─────────┐
 └─────┴────┬──────┴─────┬───────┘         │
            │     ┌──────┴─────┐     ┌─────┴──────┐
            │     │ ejbplugin1 │ ... │ ejbpluginN │
            │     └──────┬─────┘     └─────┬──────┘
     ┌──────┴────────────┴─────────────────┴───┐
     │                 model                   │
     └─────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Maybe I'm wrong in both cases. I'm out of ideas, so I'm asking my question here.
One more thing that bores me. As far as I know, every ejb-method executes in a transaction. Does it mean that whenever I start my batch of plugins in ejb method they all are executed in single transaction though they running asynchronously and ejb method is ended long ago? Does it mean that if one of plugins crashes, entire transaction is going to be reverted and all data is lost? If it so, how to workaround this?

Please feel free to answer whether you only know an answer to a part of my question or I completely wrong in my speculations.